# Why "There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘la_syevd’"?

Tags: module, fortran, fortran90, lapack

I'm using `Lapack95` to calculate some eigenvalue problem. I managed to successfully call the necessary subroutine from the main program. However, when I try to call it from a module, it issues the error:

> There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘la_syevd’'

Clearly this suggests that I did not load the proper module from inside the new module I'm developing, but it is not the case. Do you have an idea of what's going on here? This has to be a silly mistake somewhere, but I can not see it.

More concretely, the minimal example that reproduces the issue is shown below.

```
module EOF
  use F95_LAPACK, only: LA_SYEVD  !! this does not seem to load the interface here, but it does in the main program ?!
  implicit none

contains

  subroutine diagonalise(a, eigenvectors, eigenvalues)
    real, dimension(:,:), intent(in) :: a
    real, dimension(size(a,2),size(a,2)), intent(out) :: eigenvectors
    real, dimension(size(a,2)), intent(out) :: eigenvalues

    integer :: info

    call la_syevd(a=a, w=eigenvectors, jobz='V', info=info)  !!! THIS CALL DOES NOT WORK

 end subroutine

end module EOF

program mkeof
  use F95_LAPACK, only: LA_SYEVD
  use EOF

  implicit none
  integer :: i, j, info
  real, allocatable :: a(:,:), w(:)

  allocate(a(5,5), w(5))

  call random_number(a)

  call la_syevd(a=a, w=w, jobz='V', info=info)  !!! THIS CALL WORKS

  print*, 'END'

end program mkeof
```

Comment: In your successful call the argument supplied at `w` has rank 1, in your unsuccessful call the argument has rank 2.  I'm not familiar with that routine, are you sure it caters for both ranks ?  The error message suggests not.

Comment: In this set of lapack routines w is the eigenVALUES, whereas in the module the poster has w=eigenvectors. A reread of the documentation might be in order ...

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed the issue. It was a silly mistyped variable, as I meant 'eigenvalues'. The error message and my lack of familiarity with module dependences drove me to ignore that simple error and think the problem was in how I include the library.